# How to get the currently selected text in any app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to get the selected text from any application. Is there a way to send it to my app? In android there is a Share button, but how does iOS do it? Or there is another way

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way without copy/paste.

Comment: That is likely the only way, unless the developer of the other app has specifically implemented text copying through a Sharing button. It's really exactly what copy/paste is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can possibly use the UIPasteBoard API for your needs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html

There is, however not any way apps can communicate with each as apps are sandboxed on iOS and not open like you're used to with Android development.